# Should I should subclass this Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models, single-table-inheritance

I have a model called `Coupon`, which can either be set to have a `money_off` or `percent_off` attributes (it can only have one set at a time).

Also depending on whether the `Coupon` is `money_off` or `percent_off` changes which methods are used.

Im wondering if i should be using Single table inheritance to eseentially sub class `Coupon` and have a sub class that deals with **percent off coupons** and another dealing with **money off coupons**?

I would then like to know how a user would be able to select this from the view.

Comment: Well, it all depends. Inheritance is one way. [Injectable] strategies - another. Branching (`if coupon_type == :money_off`) all over the place - yet another. Hard to say what's better without knowing more about your app and its requirements.

Comment: Thanks for that, I would lik to try and avoid branching if I can do keep my code clean. I have never heard of injectable strategies before.

Comment: Any links to where I can find more info an "Injectable Strategies"?

Comment: I just made up that term :) Let me see if I can whip up a quick answer that expands on that.

Comment: Wouldn't say this calls for inheritance. What happens if you get another thing based on which to branch off?

Comment: Thanks @ndn, my concern I would be if'ing lots in my model to figure out which type of discount the coupon was.

Comment: Thanks for that @ndn, just so that Im getting the terminology correct would this be the right place to use a concern or maybe just a PORO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to determine which functionality you require for each class. If you only need a small amount of changes, then stick to a single class with an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
#app/models/coupon.rb
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum type: [:percent, :money]

   def value
      if type.percent?
         # ...
      elsif type.money?
         # ...
      end
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the `type` in your instance methods, which shouldn't cause such a problem *if* you didn't have a lot of changes to make within the class.

This would allow you to call:

```
@coupon = Coupon.find x
@coupon.value #-> returns value based on the type
```

--

The alternative (STI) would be more of a structured change, and would only work if you were referencing each class explicitly:

```
#app/models/coupon.rb
class Coupon < ActiveRecord::Base
end

#app/models/percent.rb
class Percent < Coupon
   def amount
      # ...
   end
end

#app/models/money.rb
class Money < Coupon
   def takeout
      # ...
   end
end
```

An important factor here is how you call these.

For the above classes, you have to reference the `subclassed` classes on their own:

```
@percentage_coupon = Percent.find x
@money_coupon      = Money.find y
```

This will obviously be more cumbersome, and may even cause problems with your routes & controllers etc.

.... so it may be best going with the single class :)

Comment: Wow this is great just what I was looking for

Comment: Also quick side note is it ok to name your enum `type`, I thought that was reserved?

Comment: @SamMason: I wouldn't risk it :)

Comment: Yep I think it's reserved for STI's etc; if it doesn't work just change the column name.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that illustrates the usage of strategies (about which Yam posted a more detailed answer):

```
class Coupon < Struct.new(:original_price, :amount_off, :type)
  def price_after_discount
    discount_strategy.call(self)
  end

  private

  def discount_strategy
    # note: no hardcoding here
    klass = type.to_s.camelize # :money_off to 'MoneyOff'
    "Coupon::#{klass}".constantize.new       
  end

  class MoneyOff
    def call(coupon)
      coupon.original_price - coupon.amount_off
    end
  end

  class PercentOff
    def call(coupon)
      coupon.original_price * (1.0 - coupon.amount_off / 100.0)
    end
  end
end  

Coupon.new(150, 10, :money_off).price_after_discount # => 140
Coupon.new(150, 10, :percent_off).price_after_discount # => 135.0
```

Now, instead of creating a strategy internally, we can accept it in constructor, thus making the strategy "injectable".

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is maintain the strategy internally, and provide methods such as `price`, `discounted?`, `discounted_price`. In addition, whether or not the admin chose to enter percentages or fixed units, you can still supply both methods: `discount_pct`, `discount_units` which would internally realize how to compute their return values.

This way the original class still supports the concept (same as the data model), yet is also flexible enough to allow various ways of providing it the necessary input. Whether you wish to show customers the pct off, or the fixed price units, you can do so independently of the admin's preferred method of input.

Even internal methods can use these abstractions. And if it turns out you're if/elsing all over the place internally, you can create nested classes for strategies and instantiate the right one once you get the record from the DB.

Comment: If I wanted to check to see if a coupon was percent of money off, how could I check for that with a method.

    if .coupon_type is :money-off
      self.calc_money_off
    else
       self.calc_percent_off
    end

Would something like that work?

Comment: If you have a separate table for coupons, then the model for Coupon can have a type. As for the Items, you can have a `.coupon` method returning its associated coupon (or `nil`, or some default degenerate coupon), and the item's pricing methods could rely on the type of coupon it has (or not). Then you can still use `item.price`, `item.discounted_price`, and if you wanted to know the type, `item.coupon.type if item.discounted?`.

Comment: Ah there is no Item model I will be performing the checks directly with the Coupon there wont be any associated models its not a typical shopping system